# How to double all line breaks?

Tags: php, regex

> **Edit**: The problem described below was just caused by a "feature" of my IDE, so there's actually nothing wrong with the regex. If you're interested in how to double line breaks, here's your question and answer in one neat package. :)

I want to change every line break in a string to be two line breaks:

```
"this is
an example
string"
// becomes:
"this is

an example

string"
```

However, it needs to take Unix/Windows line endings into account. I've written the code below, but it's not behaving itself.

```
$output = preg_replace("/(\r?\n)/", "$1$1", $input);
```

But it's not working. Changing the replacement string to this...

```
"$1 $1"
```

...makes it work, but then I have an unwanted space in between.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? It seems to work perfectly for me, with both UNIX and Windows linebreaks.

Comment: $1$1 is working for me in Unix and Windows too.

Comment: hmm okay, maybe it's just something strange with my output. Closing as no longer relevant.

Comment: oh man... you can't close your own questions by yourself. :-\

Comment: It's still relevant. Tell us more about your system/PHP/whatnot and see if we can figure out why it's not working for you. Also, tell us more than just "it's not working." Show us the output.

Comment: I was running this script and reading the output inside my IDE (UEStudio), and the blank lines were being collapsed by the IDE. The actual program was fine. sorry to take up everyone's time!

Comment: I recommend you answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting. I just tested your sample code on two different UNIX systems (Ubuntu and a FreeBSD box, for the record). In both cases, it worked exactly as you say you wish it to. So your platform or your configuration may be partially at fault.

Answer (score 1):

Wait Wait.  Are you just directly outputting that to the browser?  Did you **View Source?**  Returns are not shown in HTML.  Try putting `<pre>` before and `</pre>` after, if you want to view the returns as line breaks.

Comment: it's not HTML. It's being output into a file.